# Mockito : AssertionError expecting True but gives False

Tags: java, junit, boolean, mockito

It seems that when both `f.isColored() && fm.isColored()` are together the method returns false, but if i use them separately the method returns correctly true.

**This method 0 doesn't pass the test**

```
 @Override
    public boolean colorConstraint(ActionSpace as, FamilyMember fm) {
        for (FamilyMember f : as.getFamilyMembers()) {
            if (true && f.isColored() && fm.isColored()) //this does not work
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

**Test passes with this method 1**

```
@Override
    public boolean colorConstraint(ActionSpace as, FamilyMember fm) {
        for (FamilyMember f : as.getFamilyMembers()) {
            if (true && false && fm.isColored())
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

**Test passes with this method 2**

```
@Override
public boolean colorConstraint(ActionSpace as, FamilyMember fm) {
    for (FamilyMember f : as.getFamilyMembers()) {
        if (true && f.isColored() && true)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Test method**

```
 @Test
    public void neutralFMInASAndSameOwner() {
        //given
        List<FamilyMember> familyMemberList;
        familyMemberList = Arrays.asList(fm);
        when(as.getFamilyMembers()).thenReturn(familyMemberList);

/*this is commented when using method 1 */
        //family member in action space is neutral
        when(familyMemberList.get(0).isColored()).thenReturn(false);

/*this is commented when using method 2 */
        //fm to place is colored
        when(fm.isColored()).thenReturn(true);
        //when
        Boolean bool;
        bool = harvestProductionASController.colorConstraint(as, fm);
        //then
        assertTrue(bool); //AssertionError when using method 0
    }
```

Comment: Then you should do some debugging.  If you're still stuck after that, then please create a [minimal test-case](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: are you sure about this: `I don't understand why: IF( 4 == 4 && FALSE && TRUE) is returning FALSE`?? it will return TRUE only when all parameters are TRUE; this is `&` not `|`.

Comment: updated question

Answer (score 0):

```
 List<FamilyMember> familyMemberList;
 familyMemberList = Arrays.asList(fm);
 when(as.getFamilyMembers()).thenReturn(familyMemberList);

/*this is commented when using method 1 */
 //family member in action space is neutral
 when(familyMemberList.get(0).isColored()).thenReturn(false);
```

`where is familyMemberList.get(0)` it's fm , it's the same as

```
when(fm.isColored()).thenReturn(false);
```

as you add as zero element fm  into familyMemberList

so in your code it's:

when(fm.isColored()).thenReturn(false);--for first call return false
when(fm.isColored()).thenReturn(true); --for second call return true

fm - it's mocked object , for mock object mockito can works like : if call method first time then retuns X , if call method second time then returns Y.....
and it your case you applyed this behaviour.

in method `colorConstraint` you have check :

```
if (f.isColored() && fm.isColored()) //this does not work
   return false;
```

f.isColored()  has value - false
fm.isColored() has result - true

so result for this method, for your test,  is false .

fix : (don't use same object)

```
 List<FamilyMember> familyMemberList;
 FamilyMember fmNew= new ();
 familyMemberList = Arrays.asList(fmNew);
```

just remark :

change 
if (true && f.isColored() && fm.isColored()) -->(f.isColored() && fm.isColored())

if (true && false && fm.isColored()) -->if (!fm.isColored())

if (true && f.isColored() && true) -->if (f.isColored())